# Get product ID on event controller_action_predispatch_checkout_cart_add

Tags: event-observer

I'm using event controller_action_predispatch_checkout_cart_add which will be fired before adding product to cart. But in my observer function I'm not getting product id.

config:

```
  <events>
        <controller_action_predispatch_checkout_cart_add>
            <observers>
                <retailon_product_add_cart>
                    <type>singleton</type>
                    <class>retailon_productoption/observer</class>
                    <method>cartProductAddBefore</method>
                </retailon_product_add_cart>
            </observers>
        </controller_action_predispatch_checkout_cart_add>
    </events>
```

Observer function

```
    public function cartProductAddBefore(Varien_Event_Observer $observer){
        $product    = $observer->getEvent()->getProduct();
        $pId        = $product->getId();
        Mage::log('PID:'.$pId, null, 'oo.log');
    }
```

It says Fatal error: Call to a member function getId() .

I've also tried `$observer->getProduct()->getId();` but no luck.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you didn't tag your magento version i assume you are on magento 1.9.X C.E

If you need the product object after you add / update your product to the cart you need to observe this event which has the product.

```
checkout_cart_add_product_complete

 /*Mage::dispatchEvent('checkout_cart_add_product_complete',
                array('product' => $product, 'request' => $this->getRequest(), 'response' => $this->getResponse())*/
```

If you need the product id before you add the product to the cart you can get it from the params posted

```
$this->getRequest()->getParams();
```

or

```
print_r(Mage::app()->getRequest()->getParams());
```

Comment: Magento version is 1.9.x. Since I need to do some operation before adding it to cart that's why I'm using `controller_action_predispatch_checkout_cart_add` but it seems `checkout_cart_add_product_complete`  will be fired after product is added to cart.

Comment: Use Mage::app()->getRequest()->getParams() to get the product Id , qty before you add it to the cart. Just print_r(Mage::app()->getRequest()->getParams()) to get the parameters (product id and qty) that you've posted before you add it to the cart.

Comment: Sorry I'm not dispatching it from anywhere. The configuration is there in config.xml and I cannot pass product id from there.

Comment: Oh dear i know you're not passing anything ! But when you add the products to the cart the product_id and qty are posted which you can get from your observer function using this code below. $postedParams = Mage::app()->getRequest()->getParams(); print_r($postedParams);

Comment: thanks `print_r(Mage::app()->getRequest()->getParam('product'));` gives the product id.

Comment: You're welcome , if it helps you mark this as an answer, which may help others !