# Magento add custom options to cart

Tags: cart, event-observer, addtocart

I'm trying to add product's custom option to cart programmatically using event

> controller_action_predispatch_checkout_cart_add

In my observer function I'm not able to to get product object using following methods

> $observer->getProduct()->getId();

or

> $observer->getEvent()->getProduct()->getId();

Though I'm getting product Id using

> $obsPId = Mage::app()->getRequest()->getParam('product')

Check [Details here](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/83618/get-product-id-on-event-controller-action-predispatch-checkout-cart-add).

Now I've created product object using

```
$product = Mage::getSingleton('catalog/product')->load($obsPId);
```

I've created product's additional custom option in array

```
$additionalOptions = array(
                        'label' => $sareeLabel,
                        'value' => $sareeOptionId,
                    );
```

Now issue is here:
Code being used to add additional option to product

```
$product->addOption(array(
                        'code' => 'additional_options',
                        'value' => serialize($additionalOptions),
                    ));
```

**Error:** Fatal error: Call to a member function getId() on a non-object in Magento's core model Product.php.

I've also tried using observer
`$observer->getProduct()
    ->addCustomOption('additional_options', serialize($additionalOptions));`

but it gives Fatal error: Call to a member function addCustomOption() on a non-object in my observer's function.

**Questions:**

1. Is it normal in Magento that below observer functions won't work on `controller_action_predispatch_checkout_cart_add` event?
   `$observer->getProduct()->getId(); $observer->getEvent()->getProduct()->getId();`
2. In my above code, how I can add custom options to cart?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The event is called before the action `Mage_Checkout_CartController::addAction()` which calls `$this->_initProduct()` that does the load of the product.

Better set the request parameters with your custom options with `... ->getRequest()->setParam(name, value)` in your observer function.
See the parameters by adding a product in cart, log all `...->getRequest()->getParams()` in logs and see the key names of the array with custom options.

But you'll need ids of the custom options which implies at most a product load in your observer. A better implementation would be to fetch only the custom option ids and labels, not the entire prouduct (+100 SQL queries).